# SQL Server Storage Plugin not Working

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-drill

I am trying to get the SQL Server Plugin working in Apache Drill as outlined [here](http://drill.apache.org/docs/rdbms-storage-plugin/) but it seems to be throwing the following error:

```
error (unable to create/update storage)
```

My storage config looks like this:

```
{
  type: "jdbc",
  enabled: true,
  driver: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
  url:"jdbc:sqlserver://10.60.68.145;databaseName=Demo",
  username:"ApacheDrill",
  password:"Passw0rd"
}
```

I have tried copying both **sqljdbc41.jar** (from sqljdbc_4.1.5605.100_enu.tar.gz) and **sqljdbc42.jar** (from sqljdbc_4.2.6420.100_enu.tar.gz) to the drill directory **\apache-drill-1.4.0\jars\3rdparty\** but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

The environment details are:
Operating System: **Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro**, SQL Server Version: **11.0.3000** and Apache Drill Version: **1.4.0**.

Comment: I am sure you are able to connect to SQL Server  using `jdbc:sqlserver://10.60.68.145;databaseName=Demo` url with username & password. Right? Please paste the full error shown from `apache-drill-1.4.0/log/sqlline.log`(_assuming you are running in embedded mode_)

Comment: @dev ツ: Yeah I tried to connect to the SQL Server database using [SQuirreL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) via the  sqljdbc41.jar driver and everything worked OK. When I check the apache-drill-1.4.0/log/sqlline.log I can't see any entry in there relating to the SQL Server Storage Plugin not working? I only see log entries relating to queries that have been run against csv files for example which does work.

Comment: OK I just quit Drill sqlline and restarted it again and the creation of the SQL Server Storage Plugin has now worked!