# Unable to create Storage plugin for Mysql Apache Drill

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-drill

With help from the documentation : http://drill.apache.org/docs/rdbms-storage-plugin/ I've been trying to create a storage plugin for Mysql in Apache Drill, I tried multiple jdbc drivers : `mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin` , `sqlserverjdbc` but I always get the error:

```
Please retry: error (unable to create/update storage)
```

my configuration is as follows :

```
{
"type":"jdbc",
"driver":"mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin",
"url":"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306",
"username":"root",
"password":"password",
"enabled": true 
}
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't work and how to fix it please ? 
Thanks in adcance

PS: I've seen this post [SQL Server Storage Plugin not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34937696/sql-server-storage-plugin-not-working) but didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [docs](http://drill.apache.org/docs/rdbms-storage-plugin/) add this plugin.

```
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
  "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306",
  "username": "root",
  "password": "mypassword",
  "enabled": true
}
```

NOTE: Make sure you added **mysql-connector jar** in `<drill-directory>/jars/3rdparty`