# unable to create new mysql storage in apache drill

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-drill

i have a fresh installation of apache drill. and i want to add mysql storage. i've already put [mysql driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) to /opt/apache-drill-1.9.0/jars/3rdparty/. i try to create via web console. this is my configuration for mysql storage :

```
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
  "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306",
  "username": "user1",
  "password": "passworduser1",
  "enabled": true
}
```

but its getting error :

> Please retry: error (unable to create/ update storage)

does anyone know how to fix it? thanks in advance.

PS : i'v seen this post [Unable to create Storage plugin for Mysql Apache Drill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743443/unable-to-create-storage-plugin-for-mysql-apache-drill), but it's didn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download `mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar` connector and place it in `jars/3rdparty/` folder

Modify `conf/drill-override.conf` to add the below line before }:

```
drill.exec.sys.store.provider.local.path = "mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar"
```

Restart drill and try again.

Comment: thanks for helping me.. it works... another important thing is to ensure your mysql account can connect remotely... check your mysql config...